# Clone Objects opens all UI menus of all the clones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in unity I have a prefab that contains a canvas

This prefab is instatiated at runtime and can be instantiated multiple times throughout the game

Now lets assume 2 of these prefabs `Barracks` exist in the game

If I click on Barracks #1

```c#
private void OnBarrackClick(){
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && !GameManager.Instance.buildModeActive) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition), out hit, 25.0f, LayerMask.GetMask ("Barrack"))) {
                this.trainingMenu.SetActive (true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I will get the menus for both Barracks #1 and #2

However I also have an exit button on this UI

```c#
public void ExitTrainingMenu(){
        this.trainingMenu.SetActive (false);
    }
```

This exit function is called through a exit button located on the ui and it exits only the menu for that Barracks while the `SetActive` function is called through code and displays all the menus

What should be happening is only the UI for the barracks that is clicked should be displaying

How do I fix this bug and whats the cause of it?

To better demonstrate this I have uploaded a video here

http://kot90.altervista.org/survius/display.php?name=IGt6yCrYgV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't discriminating your clicks against a single building. You're only checking...

1. Is the mouse down? (this is true for both barracks)
2. Is `GameManager.Instance.buildModeActive` false? (this is true for both barracks)
3. A raycast against a Layer Mask for the "Barrack" layer (this is true for both barracks)

And if all of these things pass, display the UI.

But you have two barracks. Which one was hit? Was it *my* barracks object or was it *some other barracks* object?

Comment: gotcha it was a simple as just adding a statement saying `hit.point.transform.GetComponent<Barrack>().trainingMenu.SetActive(true)` :)

Comment: @FlamingGenius In which case, you only need one copy of this script (it is unclear if the code you posted is attached to your prefab or not). And you should really make that more generic: `hit.point.transform.GetComponent<Building>().onBuildingClicked()` and let the building decide what happens. (`Barracks` would extend `Building`).

Answer (score 0):

The cause is already explained by Draco18s but the easiest way to achieve what you want is using

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("OnMouseDown");
    canvasObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Note: Make sure a Collider is attached to the gameobject.